# Apache tuscany based restfull webservices response as json

Tags: java, rest, apache-tuscany

I developed a restful service using apache tuscany rest runtime which gives json as response. But it raises an exception:
"There is no path to send the response". How can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ans:Developing Restful services using ApacheTuscany Then We need to configure the following 
    properties in composite file.
    
      
      
       
        
           
       
         `